# Load/Stress testing an angular app

Tags: angularjs, load-testing, stress-testing, locust, artillery

I have an angular application having some issues when more than a certain amount of users logs at the same time. I wish to load/stress test it with a realy simple scenario: user sees home page, logs in, then wait 30s, then logs out. I would like to have a 200-400 users crowd.

The problem is i can't find an appropriate tool to do the job. Is there any tester here which could help me ? Already tried Artillery and locust io.

Thank you already,

Comment: Given that each user has their own copy of the app, it seems more likely that the problem is on the backend. But recommendations for tools are off topic here.

Answer (score 1):

Load testing tools are frontend-agnostic, any of [performance testing tools](http://www.opensourcetesting.org/category/testing-tools-overview/performance/?menu-page=overview) which supports HTTP protocol will fit.

Be aware that none of the load testing tools actually supports JavaScript as it is executed by browser engine while load testing tools are acting on HTTP protocol level. So if your application relies on [AJAX requests](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp) you will need to find a tool which is capable of executing JavaScript-driven HTTP Requests in parallel.

Take a look at [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/), it should be pretty easy to use. There is [Parallel Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-parallel-controller-in-jmeter) extension which makes JMeter to behave like a real browser when it comes to AJAX requests simulation.